# Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS: monit alert -- Connection failed sshd

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, monit

Overnight, I received tens of emails from the `Monit` that looked like this:

```
Connection failed Service sshd

        Date:        Thu, 24 Oct 2019 11:39:49
        Action:      restart
        Host:        my_app_production
        Description: failed protocol test [SSH] at INET[localhost:22] via TCP -- SSH: error receiving identification string -- Success


Your faithful employee,
Monit
```

and

```
Connection succeeded Service sshd

        Date:        Thu, 24 Oct 2019 11:41:50
        Action:      alert
        Host:        my_app_production
        Description: connection succeeded to INET[localhost:22] via TCP

Your faithful employee,
Monit
```

I checked the server - it's up and running. I checked out the disk space, and there's enough space.

I am not that familiar with DevOps and not sure what and where should I dig in and how to fix this problem. Googling didn't really help as well.

Any advice?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This should have been a temporary problem at amazon. I assume that you cannot review nor change the sshd config (or logs) on AWS, so I would recommend to soften the monit rules.

Just use the [fault tolerance](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#FAULT-TOLERANCE) feature:

```
if failed port 22
  # add this:
  for 2 times within 3 cycles
then alert
```